# Magento 2.2.5 Would it be possible to re-use a module

Tags: module, magento-2.2.5

I am using a module to calculate shipping rates (matrixrate) and since I want to have more shipping methods, could I re-use this module? I was thinking maybe reinstalling it? Could this work?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the main extension folder and the extension name and rename as well all the namespaces in the classes and other files.

You would need to have a look at your database and make sure you are not overriding one each other.